95% CI's extremely overlapped but p<0.05
I am comparing the AUC from two different logistic regression models coded in R using pROC (paired data).

"Data: pred2$fixed_effect in 71 controls (actual 0) < 43 cases (actual 1).
Area under the curve for model 1: 0.8852
95% CI: 0.82-0.9412 (5000 stratified bootstrap replicates)
Area under the curve for model 2: 0.9017
95% CI: 0.8413-0.9515 (5000 stratified bootstrap replicates)"

As you can see the 95% CI's are almost completely overlapping but when I perform a roc.test in r to compare both AUC's I get a significant difference:

"Bootstrap test for two correlated ROC curves
data:  model1 and model2
D = -2.2082, boot.n = 5000, boot.stratified = 1, p-value = 0.02723
alternative hypothesis: true difference in AUC is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
AUC of roc1     AUC of roc2 
0.8851949      0.9017360"

I Know if 95% CI overlap somewhat then you can still have statistical significance but in this case I would not have expected significance due to the degree of overlap. Can someone help explain what is going on?
Thanks


Are the results based on the same dataset?  If so, then it's likely they are strongly positively correlated, which fully explains these statistics.

Hi whuber, yes both AUC's are generated from two different logistic regression models  from the same dataset.  As a result I have selected a paired test giving these significance values. When I do an unpaired test I get worse (but more expected p values). I can't understand why this would be the case.

This is a universal result: the whole point of the paired test is that the pairing reduces the variance when the data are positively correlated.

Sorry if I'm being thick here whuber, I very much appreciate your help, but I don't understand how those specific 95% CI's, which overlap to such a great degree, could ever produce p<0.05.

Simple example: consider the $(x,y)$ dataset $(1,2),$ $(2,3.001),$ $(3,4).$  The CIs of the individual coordinates are wide and overlap substantially, but because the differences are nearly constant (averaging around $1$) they have a narrow CI that doesn't cover zero,

Thank you so much Whuber.. that makes complete sense now!
